# Cannot set site collection administrator, uls: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Tags: 2013, site-collection, backup, content-database

I received a SQL content database backup file (BAK) from the customer. I restored it in SQL Management Studio. I set the farm account DB owner for this content database.

I try to set in CA the site collection administrator. But it doesn't work. The input field is empty/greyed out to set some username.

In the ULS I see this error:

```
Access denied.  You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

Who knows what the issue is? I am using SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Comment: Are you Admin of the Web Application you mounted the DB on?

Comment: I created the webapplication with sp-install account. I give the sp-install account full control on webapplication with the policy permissions in CA. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean, if your admin account or your administrator group has full control on the Web Application?

Comment: Yes is has full control to the web application. Still the same issue. When I select the web application and then the root site collection (/), I see 'no selection'.

Comment: The database you restored was it a backup from a sp2010 system or an sp2013 system? Are you able to open the site and change Site Collection Admins under Site Settings?

Comment: A few things to try:
- compare users and roles in the new WSS_db with an older (pre-existing) one
- use powershell
- make sure you start CA "as administrator"

Comment: It is a backup of sp 2013. yes, thats possible. I can go to http://myportal.com/_layouts/settings.aspx.

Comment: Can you check under "Quota and Locks" in the CA, if the Site Collection set to "Read Only"?

Comment: Under "Quota and Locks" I have the same issue. I see there 'no selection' when I select the web application/root site collection.

Comment: In the Web Application under Authentication Providers on Default, enable Anonymous Access, press "Ok" (you may check if it works now) and afterwards disable it again. Then check if this solved the Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by my self. This is the fix: `Set-SPSite -Identity http://spsite -UserAccountDirectoryPath ""`

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your Central Administration as Administrator, If still grayed out , try to set it using SharePoint Management shell (open it as administrator).

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "<SiteCollection>" -SecondaryOwnerAlias "<User>"
```

If you got the same error so it's permission issue, try to check farm account user mapping for this database as the following permission

[image]

Answer (score 0):

couple of things can cuase this issue, please make sure following.

- Farm admin Account and App Pool account of the Web Application( where this db is attached) should have DBO rights on the restored db
- Restored DB should be Online in the SQL Server( no read only)
- Make sure no other content DB has the same site collection in it, attached to the farm.
- make sure enough free space on the SQL Server
- from central admin > upgrade and migration > review database status...on this page check what is the status of the DB.